# Not able to scrape a website.Getting HTML Error

Tags: python

I am trying to extract information from [this](https://ebiz.licindia.in/D2CPM/#qni/basicinfo.) website after filling the fields. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

post_params = {
  'firstName' : 'ABCD',
  'lastName' : 'EFGH',
  'dob': '12121992',
  'email' : 'dummy@gmail.com',
  'mobile': '8800443322'
}

post_args = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_params).encode("utf-8")
print (post_args)

url = 'https://ebiz.licindia.in/D2CPM/#qni/basicinfo'
fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data = post_args)

soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)
print (soup)
```

Comment: You missed the gender: `Gender is mandatory`.

Comment: It seems to be a single page built with jquery. It will require js engine to load the DOM before parsing. Checked with builtwith.com